# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pooling.Factory"

Tags: java, oracle, ucp

I'm having some sort of problem with `ucp.jar`

If I use `ucp.jar` for oracle 12.1.0.1 it works.

If I use the version for oracle 12.1.0.2 then I get the following exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pooling.Factory`

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks, Mauro

Comment: Check the documentation if that class was changed / removed ...

Comment: I've got the same problem; 12.1.0.1 works, and 12.1.0.2 throws an error about oracle.jdbc.pooling.Factory not being found.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The Jdbc (ojdbc7.jar) and UCP (ucp.jar) jars must always be from the same version (12.1.0.2). You can't upgrade one without upgrading the other. This version dependency was introduced in 12c. It wasn't the case before.

Comment: Could you please provide link to document that has this information_?

Answer (score 0):

There is a ojdbc7.jar/ojdbc6.jar file dependency. You need to download/update either depending on the java version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following maven dependencies solved the issue for me

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
                    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Register (or have an existing Oracle.com account)

**(2)** Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html

Download `ojdbc8.jar` and `udp.jar` add to classpath.

**(3)** If you use build tools (Maven or Gralde), go to directory of files `ojdbc8.jar` and `upd.jar`

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=udp.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=udp -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**(4)** If you use Gradle, you must declare use MavenLocal in `build.gradle`. Example

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.donhuvy'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 10

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc8:12.1.0.1')
    compile('com.oracle:ucp:12.1.0.1')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```